# How to POST Json file in the request body of Powershell Invoke-Webrequest

Tags: powershell

Can you please help me, How can I upload a Json file in the body of PUT request, is the following approach correct?

'''

```
$filename = "C:/Users/timtim/Downloads/default.json"
 [hashtable]$headers=@{
                'Authorization' = "Bearer $token"
                }
                $url= "url.com"
$statusCode = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method PUT -InFile $filename -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"

Write-Host "$statusCode"
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$filename = "C:/Users/timtim/Downloads/default.json"
$content = gc $filename

[hashtable]$headers=@{}

$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
$headers.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json')

$statusCode = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method PUT -Body $content -Headers $headers

Write-Host $statusCode
```

Your syntax in the $headers was off. I replaced that part by initializing the hashtable, then we add our pieces to that one at a time. I was not sure why URL was in there so I removed it. You can add that back if needed. Send your JSON in a `-body` param. There is also `$content = gc $filename` where gc is an alias for "get-content". It's getting the content of the JSON from the file with that.